# return false with .on(), still propagating

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind

I'm having a tricky time with this code.

First, I have a series of images, each within an anchor.

`a > img`

`a > img`

`a > img`

The functionality I want is, when you roll your mouse over the image it dynamically adds 2 share buttons to the anchor:

`a > .fb + .twitter + img`

When you roll off they get removed.

The problem is, I also have a lightbox which binds to the `a`. That means when you click one of the share divs, it shows the share box properly, but it also triggers the lightbox.

I have tried everything to stop this... `preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()` and `return false`. None of them stop the div click from bubbling to the anchor and triggering the lightbox.

First is my code for the rollovers. `App.postImages` is just a cached collection of jQuery image anchors. I use `.add()` to also add embedded video containers.

```
rolloverShares: {
  divs: $('<div class="image-rollover rollover-facebook">Facebook</div><div class="image-rollover rollover-twitter">Twitter</div>'),

  init: function() {
    var _this = this;
    App.postImages.add('.embed-container', '#content-wrapper').hover(
      function() {
        _this.divs.prependTo($(this)).show();
      },
      function() {
        $('div', this).remove();
      }
    );

    $(document).on('click', '.rollover-facebook', function() {
      Social.facebook.popup();
      return false;
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.rollover-twitter', function() {
      Social.twitter.popup();
      return false;
    });
  }
},
```

Here is my lightbox code. Nothing fancy. If it matters, the `.on()` in the block below makes it so you can click anywhere on the lightbox to close it, not just the image.

```
lightbox: function() {
  if (isDesktop) {
    App.postImages.nivoLightbox({
      effect: 'fade', 
      theme: 'default',
      keyboardNav: false,
      clickOverlayToClose: true,
      errorMessage: 'The requested image cannot be loaded. Please try again later.'
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.nivo-lightbox-image img', function() {
      $(this).closest('.nivo-lightbox-overlay').find('.nivo-lightbox-close').click();
    });
  } else {
    App.postImages.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }
},
```

Also I suppose i should put what's in `App.postImages`. It's just this:

`$('a img', '#content-wrapper').not('.share-button img').parent().addClass('post-image')`

Comment: I haven't looked too much into your code, but it looks like you're running `return false` in a `document` event handler. That's the last stop for propagation, so what do you expect it to prevent?

Comment: You bound the event to the document. By the time the event reaches the document, the lightbox has already happened.

Comment: hmm, @KevinB what else would I bind it to? If you put an answer I will mark it. I have tried in the past and anytime I use anything other than `$(document)` it never seems to work.

Comment: In this case you would have to bind it directly to the element to stop the lightbox. And it would have to be done before the lightbox part happens.